# Изучение yii

Tags: yii

Всем доброго времени суток. Вот хочу спросить совет. С чего начать изучение php-фреймворка yii. Нужно разобраться чем скорее, тем лучше. Просто все советуют по-разному.

Есть знания ООП, правда С++. В php классами не пользовался, да и изучать я его начал месяца 2 назад только. Но работать нужно в yii. Каковой может быть последовательность. Хотелось бы это услышать от опытных пользователей фреймворков, дабы совершать поменьше ошибок при изучении и минимизировать эти сроки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как и везде - главное начать, дальше легче. Попробуй создать небольшой проект, посмотреть на примеры готовых проектов.

Наверное самое главное - это научится применять и пользоваться принципами ООП. Старайся не повторять ни себя ни разработчиков Yii. Всю документацию можно посмотреть на их сайте http://yiiframework.com/doc/api/, плюс в сети есть куча примеров. Ну и самый достоверный источник - исходники. Если возникнуть вопросы - лезь вначале в исходники, потом в документацию. Погляди исходники хороших расширений и модулей, чтобы лучше понять, как все устроено.

Попробуй найти книжки по Yii (на сайте есть информация про них), не знаю есть ли они на русском. Ну и как всегда - книги по ООП и методологиям. Само собой - по PHP (в сети полно рекомендаций).

PS. Однозначного ответа на твой вопрос не существует.

Comment: Ну уж в исходниках новичку копаться - само то! :)

Comment: А как ты по-другому поймешь, что внутри творится? Как научишься писать качественный код? По документации?

Answer (score 3):

Начните с чтения документации "Она есть на русском языке",это вполне поможет. А дальше ставьте фрейм.. и пробуйте, пробуйте, пробуйте.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите и изучайте отдельные элементы в зависимости от надобности. Т.е. смотрите по конкретной задаче и разбирайтесь. Нет смысла сразу всю документацию читать. Возьмите легкий старт, чтобы хотя бы сделать при помощи библиотеки что-то вроде Hello World, дальше смотрите по задачам.

Answer (score 2):

Первым делом сделайте блог по примеру как у них на сайте(там есть детальное описание что и как), затем надо пробовать самостоятельно другой проект. Желательно реальный. Первый блин будет огромным комом и скорее всего очень долго делаться будет. Зато Вы поймете что и как можно улучшить. Читать кучу документации не вижу смысла, да ознакомиться с основными понятиями надо, но не более. Заглядывать туда стоит по мере необходимости. Ну и конечно же есть форумы, туториалы и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

К официальной документации я бы посоветовал также руководство [Yii для начинающих](http://www.prostosem.in.ua/article/yii-dlja-nachinajushih-chast-1), в нём есть интересные примеры использования Yii.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение ко всему вышесказанному, вот [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF) на неплохие видеоуроки по Yii2. Что важно, источник живой и обновляется.